# Tooltip inside PHP

Tags: php, css, tooltip

```
$story1 = ("<br /><br />But <u><b><span class='hint--top' data-hint='soft'>$noun1</span>
```

I'm trying to make a span around one word with a linked css style sheet. The class does not want to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show source of html what you got

Comment: $story1 = "<br/><br/>But <u><b><span class='hint--top' data-hint='soft'>".$noun1."</span>";

This is a smaller piece of code

Comment: @user2879652 [Have a look at what I posted below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19543932/1415724)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tested

Give this code a try if that is the expected results you are looking to get.

The following will output **"But This is a noun"** having `This is a noun` underlined and in light gray color.

```
<?php

$noun1 = "This is a noun";
$story1 = "<br /><br />But <u><b><span class='hint--top' data-hint='soft'>$noun1</span>";
echo $story1;

?>

<style>

.hint--top {
color:#cccccc;
}

</style>
```

**NOTE:** I suggest you close your `<u>` and `<b>` tags, otherwise the rest of your HTML will show up as underlined and bold.

Change this line in "my" code:

```
$story1 = "<br /><br />But <u><b><span class='hint--top' data-hint='soft'>$noun1</span>";
```

to:

```
$story1 = "<br /><br />But <u><b><span class='hint--top' data-hint='soft'>$noun1</span></b></u>";
```

if that is the case. I don't know if your code is dynamically-generated.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Thank you Shankar, and yours too, cheers! +1 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error on your code. You need to close the quotes properly. [*Modified Code Below*]

```
$story1 = "<br /><br />But <u><b><span class='hint--top' data-hint='soft'>".$noun1."</span>";
```

Comment: @user2879652 This should work and I tested Shankar's code with mine and it works. You need to show us your entire code and how you're using it.